# Slow Down Object movement in java JOGL

Tags: java, jogl

Using `Thread.sleep(milliseconds)` would delay execution of the whole program for the specified milliseconds. My problem is how do I slow down (not delay) object movement from one container into another container in my java code (implemented using JOGL - from canvas context) , so that the movement is noticeable which otherwise happens so fast?

Here is my approach for the problem:
 I use `Stack` to represent the amount of objects on each containers. Whenever user clicks on either of the container[source], the containers `Stack` is to be popped until it is empty. At the same time `Stack` of the destination container is to be pushed. for each iteration, the containers are redrawn containing objects represented by their corresponding `Stack` size.

fraction of the code relevant for this Question:

```java
public void moveObjects(Container source, Container destination) {
  while (!source.stack.isEmpty()) {
    destination.stack.push(destination.stack.size() + 1);
    source.stack.pop();
    //redraw both containers with their new amount of objects represnted using their stack size
  }
}
```

or

```java
public void moveObject(int source, int dest) {
  while (!this.container[source].stack.isEmpty()) {
    this.container[dest].stack.push(this.container[dest].stack.size() + 1);
    this.container[source].stack.pop();
    try {
      Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
      // Handle exception here
    }
  }
}
```

I have only managed to move the objects from the source to destination one by one but the movement is too fast to be noticed by eye. How do I aproach this problem?

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking. Could you describe the problem in more detail? Preferably with code.

Comment: Ok , let me write the actual code I have

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want to move multiple objects visibly on the screen without this happening instantaneous.

As you have noticed `Thread.sleep(time)` is a bad idea as it freezes the whole application.

A way around this is to supply your update logic with the elapsed time:

```
long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
while(running)
{
  long now = System.nanoTime();
  updateLogic(now-lastTime); //this handles your application updates
  lastTime = now;
}

void updateLogic(long delta)
{
   ...
   long movementTimespan +=delta
   if(movementTimespan >= theTimeAfterWhichObjectsMove)
   {
       //move objects here
       //...
       movementTimespan -= theTimeAfterWhichObjectsMove;
   }

   //alternatively you could calculate how far the objects have moved directly from the delta to get a smooth animation instead of a jump
   //e.g. if I want to move 300 units in 2s and delta is x I have to move y units now

}
```

This allows you to track the time since the last update/frame and if you use it for animation it makes the speed of the object movement independent from the executing systems spees.

Comment: I am working around your answer. what's the line "lastTime =0 now;"

Comment: a typo ^_^' I have corrected it. It just resets the lastTime to the current one.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am still puzzled with it though. I wish you suggest me a good read on this.

Comment: Googling for "opengl game loop" or "animation loop" should turn up some examples and tutorials e.g. [this one](https://shivansite.wordpress.com/2013/10/12/the-basics-of-game-loop-implementation-part-1/)

Comment: Never call Thread.sleep() in your JOGL rendering code, it can break the GPU synchronization and ruin your performance. If you need some advises about Java game programming, you should go to Java-Gaming.org (but don't tell them that you use JOGL to avoid starting another flame war).